# Need assistance with Selection Box Compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to generate a selection box for user input, in which they select from a few options when they launch the macro, to change the footer on the output.

I pulled this code example from the internet for Selection Boxes, But am getting a

"Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined"

```
Sub FooterTest123()
' creates variables
Dim varArrayList As Variant
Dim strSelected As String
' array for selection options
varArrayList = Array("value1", "value2", "value3")
strSelected = SelectionBoxSingle(List:=varArrayList, Prompt:="Select Location")
If Len(strSelected) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print strSelected
End If
End Sub
```

Anyone have any ideas on how i can get this selection box to work?

Comment: Where is the definition for `SelectionBoxSingle`? It's not a built-in function... If you copied this from some website, you have to copy the function definition too.

Comment: If you got this code from http://codevba.com/office/selectionbox.htm, note that you have to download http://codevba.com/download.htm. I wouldn't do that though, seems like a waste of money.

Comment: I do not see a function defenition...https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/872025/VBA-Macro-User-Interaction-With-SelectionBox

Comment: How would you suggest I enable my macro to output with multiple footers?  It essentially uses the used range on the Worksheet , formats it, and exports it to PDF.  However, i wanted some sort of input to ensure that the footer information reflects the correct location for the person using it...

Comment: *You can import the SelectionBox modules into your Excel project from the SelectionBoxDemo file downloadable with this project. In addition you need to set a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library  (menu: Tools > References)*... from the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks.  This is on a work computer, so i doubt i can download anything/ install it into excel.